# Need to enable cookies and javascript in CefSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, cefsharp, .net

Когда я пытаюсь открыть сайт на CefSharp87.1.13 я получаю следующее сообщение

> please enable cookies and javascript to access this site

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу исправить её? В аргументах CefSettings ничего подходящего не смог найти

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions).

Comment: `CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;` + `CefSharpSettings.WcfEnabled = true;`? [Тынц офдок](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/87.1.x/html/Properties_T_CefSharp_CefSharpSettings.htm) + [тынц FAQ](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CallJS) А вообще, приведите свой код для начала.